# Lenovo IdeaPad N580 - Windows 7 - Optiarc DVD RW AD-7740H

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, dvd, lenovo-laptop

I recently formatted my IdeaPad N580 laptop, it came with Windows 8 installed and i downgraded to Windows 7, the Optiarc DVD RW device stopped working, more specifically it "works" but the drivers are messed up (my assumption), it flashes the light, opens/close the tray and even makes noise as if it were trying to read the CD/DVD but all/any CD/DVD i tried with does not execute nor even appears as if there were nothing, the device itself does not appear in the system, no icons.

The drivers (Windows 7 Default drivers) do not work and the manufacturer does not provide a driver download for that model in their site.

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

This is the relevant section of my DxDiag:

```
------------------
System Information
------------------
Time of this report: 4/1/2013, 19:59:47
       Machine name: USUARIO-PC
   Operating System: Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1 (7601.win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)
           Language: Spanish (Regional Setting: Spanish)
System Manufacturer: LENOVO
       System Model: 20182
               BIOS: InsydeH2O Version 03.72.275ECN91WW(V8.03)
          Processor: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU B960 @ 2.20GHz (2 CPUs), ~2.2GHz
             Memory: 4096MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 3962MB RAM
          Page File: 847MB used, 7076MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\Windows
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
   User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
     DxDiag Version: 6.01.7601.17514 32bit Unicode

------------------------
Disk & DVD/CD-ROM Drives
------------------------
      Drive: C:
 Free Space: 272.3 GB
Total Space: 305.1 GB
File System: NTFS
      Model: HITACHI HTS545032A7E380 ATA Device

      Drive: E:
      Model: ELBY CLONEDRIVE SCSI CdRom Device
     Driver: c:\windows\system32\drivers\cdrom.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (Spanish), , 0 bytes

      Drive: D:
      Model: Optiarc DVD RW AD-7740H ATA Device
     Driver: c:\windows\system32\drivers\cdrom.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (Spanish), , 0 bytes
```

Comment: Have you tried the drivers at [Optiarc DVD RW AD-7740H Drivers Download](http://www.driverscape.com/download/optiarc-dvd-rw-ad-7740h)? There are 3 different downloads for Windows 7

Comment: After updating the driver with the one provided there it says "Windows determined the driver is updated" and it still doesn't work.